# Swift Image Rotation showing 50% image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

I'm new in swift and iPhone development. Recently I'm working on a topic where I have to rotate the image vertically.

I've almost solved the issue but problem is my image is rotating but while it's rotating it's showing 50% image. Here is the link of the issue in video. http://screencast.com/t/VI4yZ0a8Wr

Also here the code i'm using

```
func animationRotationEffect(view:UIView,animationTime:Float)
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(animationTime), animations: { () -> Void in

        /* previously used
         same result produced as below
        var animation:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        animation.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI), 1, 0, 0))

        animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(animationTime)
        animation.cumulative = false
        animation.repeatCount  = 1
        view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
        */


        let animate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
        animate.duration = CFTimeInterval(animationTime)
        animate.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animate.fromValue = 0.0
        animate.toValue = Float(M_PI * 2.0)
        view.layer.addAnimation(animate, forKey: nil)

    })
}
```

It would be very helpful if anyone can help me on this.

Thanks in advance,

Nixon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not an animation problem, try setting the aspect and content mode of your `UIImageView` to this

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

More info about UIViewContentMode enumeration [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode)

Comment: I think it's not the issue. Because I already set Aspect Fit from story board. http://screencast.com/t/RfoIvZP5e. also tried your solution it did not work. :(